# Example of a nontrivial finite covering map

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, covering-spaces

A covering map $p:C\to X$ is called finite when for each $x\in X$ the fiber of $x$ is finite. I have to prove something about such covering maps, but I have never seen a nontrivial example of one. Could you give me some simple and preferably well-behaved examples? What I think I mean by a trivial covering map is one where $C=\bigsqcup\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$ with homeomorphisms $p_i:X_i\to X$ and $p(x_i)=p_i(x_i)$ for $x_i\in X_i.$

I had a couple of ideas but none worked. For example I tried to take the function $p:\Bbb R\to S_1$, $p(t)=(\cos t,\sin t)$ and restrict it to some bounded intervals (open or not), but that doesn't seem to be right. I also folded a plane and tried projecting it onto a half-plane parallel to it, but this doesn't work either, unless I'm wrong of course.

Comment: Consider the maps $z\in S^1\mapsto z^n\in S^1$ (viewing the circle $S^1$ as the set of complex numbers of modulus $1$, so that it makes sense to multiply them)

Comment: BTW, you are right that you are wrong about your example: the restriction of your $p$ to a bounded interval is never a covering of $S^1$, and you should **prove** this before continuing.

Comment: @Mariano This means I'm right actually! :) That's what I found out when I tried these examples -- that they're not examples. My "unless I'm wrong" was meant to mean "if they're actually examples".

Comment: @Mariano Thank you for the example! Why don't you post is as an answer?

Comment: Well, if you had read the wikipedia page on covering spaces, you'd found that example :-)

Comment: @Mariano Fair enough. Should I delete the question then? Perhaps there are other simple examples worth seeing at my beginner level?

Comment: Don't delete the question. There are many cute examples, someone with time might add them.

Comment: @Bartek: Other simple examples are $\mathbb{S}^n \to \mathbb{R}P^n$.

Answer (score 2):

There are, of course, a lot of examples of finite covering maps.

A (slightly) less common class of examples that comes to mind are finite coverings of the torus. Consider, for instance, the discrete lattice $\Gamma \colon=\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}i\subsetneq\mathbb{C}$, i.e. the the Gaussian integers. Take the complex number $\alpha\colon=1+i \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. Next, observe that we have $\alpha\Gamma\subset \Gamma$. Thus the map
$$p\colon\mathbb{C}/\Gamma\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}/\Gamma; [z]_\Gamma\longmapsto [\alpha\cdot z]_{\Gamma}$$ is well-defined. It is moreover a covering map. This can be seen by showing that it is a local homeomorphism (hint: $p$ induces a map $\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$) and that it satisfies the curve lifting property (for every curve $u\colon [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}/\Gamma$ and every point $y\in \mathbb{C}/\Gamma$ with $u(0)=p(y)$, there exists a lifting $\hat{u}\colon [0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}/\Gamma$ of $u$ such that $\hat{u}(0)=y$). Since $\mathbb{C}/\Gamma$ is a manifold, this implies that $p$ is a covering map, as proven in Theorem 4.19 in Forster's *Lectures on Riemann Surfaces*.

By one of the isomorphism theorem of groups, the degree of the covering map $p$ is equal to the index of the subgroup $\alpha\Gamma$ in $\Gamma$. In our example, the index is equal to $\vert \alpha \vert^2=2$.

Answer (score 1):

The Möbius band $M$ can be obtained as follows. Let the group $\mathbb{Z}$ act on the strip $S=\mathbb{R}\times[-1,1]$ as
$$n\cdot(x,t)=(x+n,(-1)^nt).$$
Then $M=S/\mathbb{Z}$.

So, if you consider the subgroup $H=2\mathbb{Z}$ the quotient $C=M/H$, in fact a cylinder, is a finite cover of $M$.

More generally every time you have a group $\Gamma$ acting "nicely enough" on a space $X$ and $\Gamma^\prime$ is a subgroup of $\Gamma$ of finite index then the natural map
$$
X/\Gamma^\prime\longrightarrow X/\Gamma
$$
is a finite cover. This generalizes all the examples given so far.